# Launch app on incoming call (android)

Tags: android

I have an app on Android that reacts to incoming calls.
Now, since the OS shuts my app down whenever it want,
I need a way to to listen to the incoming calls and launch the app when it happens.

Will a BroadcastReceiver help? (just like launching on device restart)

Any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question. This is just the sort of thing a broadcast receiver is meant for. If the receiver is registered in your manifest then the application does not have to be running.

It will be automatically started when a matching intent is broadcast. Typically the response will be to update content or activities, make notifications with the Notification manager or launch/manipulate services.

**Note** that there is a 5 second execution limit in the BroadcastReceiver onReceive handler to ensure you do not try to do any 'heavy lifting' in it. Exceed this and a force close dialog will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a BroadcastReceiver would to the job as it will fire even you app is not running.